# Matplotlib blitting multiple artists

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm trying to create an annimated Matplotlib chart that uses blitting.  I would like to include, a scatter plot, line plots, and annotations all in the same subplot.  However, all the examples I have found, e.g., https://matplotlib.org/gallery/animation/bayes_update.html seem to only return a single artist, e.g., just a line plot. (I think I'm using the artist term correctly, but may not be.)

I've tried to wrap multiple artists together but that seems not to work.  For example in the below, the plot line does not get updated and if blit is set to True I get an AttributeError: 'Artists' object has no attribute 'set_animated'

```
from collections import namedtuple

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


Artists = namedtuple('Artists', ('scatter', 'plot'))

artists = Artists(
  ax.scatter([], []),
  ax.plot([], [], animated=True)[0],
  )


def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return artists,


def update(frame):
    artists.scatter.set_offsets([[0, 0]])
    artists.plot.set_data([0, 1], [0, 1])
    return artists,

ani = FuncAnimation(
  fig=fig,
  func=update,
  init_func=init,
  blit=True)

plt.show()
```

What is the right way to do blitting with multiple artists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`FuncAnimation`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) documentation  says

> `func` : callable
>   The function to call at each frame. The first argument will be the next value in frames. Any additional positional arguments can be supplied via the fargs parameter.
>
> The required signature is:
>
> ```
>    def func(frame, *fargs) -> iterable_of_artists:
> ```

So the return type should be a list, tuple or generally an iterable of `Artists`.

When using `return artists,` you return an iterable of iterables of artists.

So you can remove the comma,

```
return artists
```

---

More generally, the named tuple seems to confuse more than it helps here, so why not simply return a tuple?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

scatter = ax.scatter([], [])
plot = ax.plot([], [], animated=True)[0]

def init():
    ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
    ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    return scatter, plot


def update(frame):
    scatter.set_offsets([[0, 0]])
    plot.set_data([0, 1], [0, 1])
    return scatter, plot

ani = FuncAnimation(
        fig=fig,
        func=update,
        init_func=init,
        blit=True)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I was trying to make that way too complicated.  Thank you!